# Dragging a file With DDEffect Move to explorer. Explorer returns DragDropEffect Nothing

Tags: vb.net

Whilst using the following code with the DragDropEffects as copy. When The object is dragged and dropped to explorer DoDragDrop correctly returns Copy

```
Dim FT As Specialized.StringCollection = New Specialized.StringCollection
FT.Add(FileName)

Dim Drag_Dat As DataObject = New DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop)
Drag_Dat.SetFileDropList(FT)

Dim DEffect As DragDropEffects = Me.DoDragDrop(Drag_Dat, DragDropEffects.Copy)

DEffect="Copy"
```

When I change the following line to Move, DoDragDrop returns nothing. The file is successfully moved but explorer isn't reporting it as moved. Why is this, is windows using a copy then delete method or something?

```
Dim DEffect As DragDropEffects = Me.DoDragDrop(Drag_Dat, DragDropEffects.Move)

DEffect="Nothing"
```

I need to be able to confirm the file has been successfully moved. I'm not looking for a work around, eg... Delete the original file if copy was successful as this can cause issues for example dropping the file into Chrome which can read the File List and in effect return Copy.

Comment: might it be a permissions issue with one of the folders?

Comment: If there were a permission issue I'd assume the move wouldn't be performed. Though I'm now starting to wonder if move doesn't actually exist anymore... moving a file on the same drive only updates the index information. I'll try the drag and drop onto a different drive to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem today and spent an hour searching for a solution...

Meanwhile you will also have the problem solved, will you.
Nevertheless I want to leave the solution here, for all others that stumble over this thread...

Because you get an NONE instead of MOVE, you can check if the file was picked up by the explorer and moved elsewhere...

```
     Effect = TreeView1.DoDragDrop(DObj, DragDropEffects.Copy Or DragDropEffects.Move)

     Select Case Effect
        Case DragDropEffects.Copy

        Case DragDropEffects.Move
            ' Never happenes

        Case DragDropEffects.None
            ' Trick !
            If Not IO.File.Exists(File) Then
                ' Do what should be done when moved....
                ......
            End If
    End Select
```